# Am I expanding grad v, which is in index notation, correctly? Is equation 10b wrong?

Tags: vector-analysis

[image: From 1]

From [1; Equation 6b], $ \mathbf T = \mathbf a \mathbf b = \mathbf \nabla \mathbf v = \frac{\partial}{\partial x_m} v_n \mathbf i_m \mathbf i_n$.

$\frac{\partial v_n}{\partial x_m}(\mathbf i_m\mathbf i_n) = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}\mathbf i_1\mathbf i_1+ \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_1 }\mathbf i_1\mathbf i_2 + \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_1}\mathbf i_1 \mathbf i_3 +\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2}\mathbf i_2 \mathbf i_1 + \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2}\mathbf i_2 \mathbf i_2 + \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_2}\mathbf i_2 \mathbf i_3 + \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_3}\mathbf i_3 \mathbf i_1 + \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_3}\mathbf i_3 \mathbf i_2 + \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_3}\mathbf i_3\mathbf i_3$

which, based on [Dyadics](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics), is a summation of determinates listed as:

=$\begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1} \cdot 1&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&0 \end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} 0& \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_1} \cdot 1 &0\\ 0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix} 0&0&\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_1}\cdot 1\\0&0&0\\0&0&0\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}0&0&0\\\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2}\cdot 1&0&0\\0&0&0\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}0&0&0\\0&\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2}\cdot 1&0\\0&0&0\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_2}\cdot 1\\0&0&0\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_3}\cdot 1&0&0\end{vmatrix} + \begin{vmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_3}\cdot 1&0\end{vmatrix}+ \begin{vmatrix}0&0&0\\0&0&0\\0&0&\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_3}\cdot 1 \end{vmatrix} = \begin{vmatrix}\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_1}&\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_1}\\ \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2}&\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2}&\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_2}\\\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_3}&\frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_3}&\frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_3} \end{vmatrix}$

Which matches the definition from[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics).

**Question:** Based on the above, is the following definition of grad $\mathbf v$ wrong,[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UWFk.png)?

[image]

Upon expansion it would be:

$\frac{\partial v_m}{\partial x_k}(\mathbf i_m\mathbf i_k) = \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_1}\mathbf i_1\mathbf i_1+ \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_1 }\mathbf i_2\mathbf i_1 + \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_1}\mathbf i_3 \mathbf i_1 +\frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_2}\mathbf i_1 \mathbf i_2 + \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_2}\mathbf i_2 \mathbf i_2 + \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_2}\mathbf i_3 \mathbf i_2 + \frac{\partial v_1}{\partial x_3}\mathbf i_1 \mathbf i_3 + \frac{\partial v_2}{\partial x_3}\mathbf i_2 \mathbf i_3 + \frac{\partial v_3}{\partial x_3}\mathbf i_3\mathbf i_3$

It appears the basis vectors are switched on $\mathbf 10b$, which, according to 1, would be the $\mathbf T^T$.

[image]

References:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0UWFk.png) Warsi, Z.U.A.. Fluid Dynamics. Taylor and Francis CRC ebook account. Kindle Edition.

[2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics) Tobias Holzmann. Mathematics, Numerics, Derivations and OpenFOAM(R), Holzmann CFD, Leoben, fourth edition, February 2017. URL:  [www.holzmann-cfd.de](https://%20www.holzmann-cfd.de)

Comment: I would really appreciate if someone can verify. I am pretty confident it is an error, but I am new to tensor mathematics. I believe [this](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dyadics#Three-dimensional_Euclidean_space) verifies the error, but wikipedia could be wrong.

Comment: My first expansion and $\mathbf 6b$ equation seems to verify that $\mathbf 10b$ is wrong. I just want an experienced member to verify.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the confusion came from the way eq. 10(b) is written from eq. 10(a). $\ i_m$ should not be placed before $i_k$. I can rewrite in the following manner to make confusion go away,
$$grad\ V = \ (\frac{\delta}{\delta x_i}i)\ (V_j\ j)$$
Now since there are two non-repeating indexes (i.e., i and j), so $grad\ V$ is definitely second order tensor. One other way to remember is that gradient always increases the order of tensor and divergence always decreases the order of the tensor. for example, a vector is a first-order tensor, therefore, the gradient of a vector is a second-order tensor while the divergence of a vector is a scaler (zeroth order tensor). Hence from the above eq. we can write the second order tensor as,
$$ grad\ V\ = \begin{bmatrix}
   \frac{\delta\ V_1}{\delta x_1} &
\frac{\delta\ V_2}{\delta x_1} & 
   \frac{\delta\ V_3}{\delta x_1} \\
   \frac{\delta\ V_1}{\delta x_2} &
   \frac{\delta\ V_2}{\delta x_2} &
\frac{\delta\ V_3}{\delta x_2} \\
\frac{\delta\ V_1}{\delta x_3} &
\frac{\delta\ V_2}{\delta x_3} & 
\frac{\delta\ V_3}{\delta x_3}
   \end{bmatrix}$$

Comment: Thank you for the answer and clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Because I saw the equation repeated later in Mathematical Exposition 1 of [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vz0e.png), I became concerned that the fluid dynamics textbook[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vz0e.png) was faulty. I doubted the author was this incompetent because he was well known. So, I researched it further and found[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTQl.png).

Apparently, some authors do consider the del operator as a vector, and my original definition in the above Mathematics Stack Exchange question would be true. In that case, Dr. Warsi's equation 10b would be the transpose as I describe in the above Mathematics Stacks Exchange question.

Other authors[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTQl.png), Dr. Warsi, go beyond the cartesian coordinate system and describe the grad(v), where v is a vector, in a manner as equation 10b is listed. It is used for tensor greater than a rank 0. I assume it will work for any coordinate system. Anyhow, the author is supposed to define which form they use, because both forms are used by authors, and there is much confusion about the two forms. Dr. Warsi did describe it later.

[image]

Which follow reference [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTQl.png) definition:

[image]

References:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1Vz0e.png) Warsi, Z.U.A.. Fluid Dynamics. Taylor and Francis CRC ebook account. Kindle Edition.

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MFTQl.png) Mortensen, Mikael. MEK2200 Notes on notation. URL: https://mikaem.github.io/mek2200/