# Two Different Matrices defined for grad v in Fluid dynamics, where v is a vector. Why the discrepancy?

Tags: vector-analysis, tensor-products

I hope to study fluid dynamics and computational fluid dynamics, but I have come across two different definitions of grad $\mathbf v$ where $\mathbf v$ is a vector.

First, from [1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCOMy.png), the grad is defined as:

[image]

Where the del operator is treated as a "special vector". From [5], this is valid for a Cartesian coordinate system.

Another definition that I found in [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIdh.png), [3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRG9m.png), and [5] describes the del operator as an operator for tensors greater than a scalar with matrix expansion:

[image]

As one can see, one is the transpose of the other, and I discuss the confusion here as well:  [Am I expanding grad v, which is in index notation, correctly? Is equation 10b wrong?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4266972/am-i-expanding-grad-v-which-is-in-index-notation-correctly-is-equation-10b-wr)

Reference [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIdh.png) also mentions that grad $\mathbf a$ is not equal to $\nabla \otimes \mathbf a$. Rather, ref [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIdh.png) specifically states that $(\nabla \otimes \mathbf a)^T = grad \ \mathbf a$. Note, my fluid dynamics text uses the same definition as [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIdh.png).

[image]

Reference [5] mentions that the author is supposed to state which form they use. Still, I am confused. Which grad is the preferred matrix representation in fluid dynamics. Why is one the transpose of the other? I would assume, as an example, the Navier-stokes equations would use one form over the other.

References:

[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yCOMy.png)  Tobias Holzmann. Mathematics, Numerics, Derivations and OpenFOAM URL: https://holzmann-cfd.com/publications/301_mathematicsNumericsDerivationsAndOpenFOAMFree/MathematicsNumericsDerivationsAndOpenFOAM_v7_free.pdf

[2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PiIdh.png) 1.14 Tensor Calculus I: Tensor Fields. URL: [http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/~pkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_1_Vectors_Tensors/Vectors_Tensors_14_Tensor_Calculus.pdf](http://homepages.engineering.auckland.ac.nz/%7Epkel015/SolidMechanicsBooks/Part_III/Chapter_1_Vectors_Tensors/Vectors_Tensors_14_Tensor_Calculus.pdf)

[3](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PRG9m.png) [4](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sLw5p.png) Warsi, Z.U.A.. Fluid Dynamics. Taylor and Francis CRC ebook account. Kindle Edition.

[5] Mortensen, Mikael. MEK2200 Notes on notation. URL: https://mikaem.github.io/mek2200/

Comment: Note, I posted in math, instead of physics, because I am allowed more links since I have greater than 10 reputation points.

Comment: please see [What topics can I ask about here?](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: The fundamental reason for the discrepancy comes down to handedness (aka Orientation: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orientability). You can essentially define many things related to the geometry of an orientable shape in 2 equivalent ways, and the net difference is what sign things will take. An example happens with left v. right actions of vector fields on smooth manifolds (one difference is that the sign of the Lie bracket changes depending on which side the vector fields act on).